# What is on Red Line?

Tags: one-piece

At one of the intersections of Grand Line and Red Line are both Mariejois and the Fishmen Island. I believe it is the only way to go to the "New World". Since we don't know much about it, I was wondering what kind of secrets it could hide.

What exactly is Red Line and what is on it?

[image]

Comment: There is nothing much told about Red Line. But it is very mysterious question why that wall even their in the first place!!!

Answer (score 5):

The Red Line is basically a group of islands connected together.

We know that it has it's own season islands, as explained by Nami

> The Red Line that crosses the Grand Line has its own Summer, Winter, Spring and Fall "islands" [chapter 604](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_604)

It is 10,000 meters deep, bears the world capital [Mariejois](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Mariejois), as stated by Hachi.

> The Red Line bears the world capital, Mariejois, and is said to be 10,000 meters deep from ocean level to Fishman Island [chapter 496](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_496)

Due to the same height, it is also considered impassable, all though this has been proven to not be the case as

- [Fisher Tigre](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Fisher_Tiger) Managed to climb the redline to attack Mariejois as told by Boa Hancock in [chapter 521](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_521)
- Germa66 passed it with an amphibious ship in [chapter 841](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_841)

Besides the sheer height, it is also considered indestructible, as demonstrated by Laboon in [chapter 104](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Chapter_104), as he had been ramming the red line to no avail for a considerable amount of time.